# Sharepoint not saving attachment on EditForm.aspx

Tags: javascript, attachments, edit-form

I'm customizing the default EditForm.aspx of a list in Sharepoint with Javascript directly on a Script Editor content webpart on the page.

One item that I have customized is the Save Button event.

Fisrt I remove the default event of the Button:

```
$("[name*='SaveItem']:visible").removeAttr("onclick");
```

After I use my custom code to save form

```
    $("[name*='SaveItem']:visible").on("click", function(e){
        $("#loading").show();

        var answer = confirm("Save Item?");
        if (answer)
        {
            if (!PreSaveItem()){    
                return false;
            }

            if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')){                  
                return false;                   
            }   

            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions($("[name*='SaveItem']:visible").attr("id"), "", true, "", document.location.origin, false, true));
        }
        else{
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
```

When I try to attach a item, everything seems correct. The file appears in the final of the form.

But when I click to Save, all fields are updated, but the attachment file is not saved in the item.

Note: If I follow the same steps but click on default Save Button on the sharepoint ribbon, the attachmente is saved on item.

Any suggestions to try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with you initial code in the line where you call `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions`:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
    new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
        $("[name*='SaveItem']:visible").attr("id"), // eventTarget
        "", // eventArgument
        true, // validation
        "", // validationGroup
        document.location.origin, // actionUrl
        false, // trackFocus
        true)); // clientSubmit
```

Looking at the code of the original `onclick` event of the save button, it expects different values for the first (eventTarget) and fifth (actionUrl) parameter:

- Instead of the `id` of the button, the first parameter should actually be the `name` attribute of the button (the `id` is basically the `name` with all `$` replaced by `_`)
- Instead of `document.location.origin`, an empty string (`""`) is expected as the actionUrl

So the changed line should look like this:

```
WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
    new WebForm_PostBackOptions(
        $("[name*='SaveItem']:visible").attr("name"), // eventTarget
        "", // eventArgument
        true, // validation
        "", // validationGroup
        "", // actionUrl
        false, // trackFocus
        true)); // clientSubmit
```

*The answer by Anders Aune is actually not correct, as `window.form` refers to the same object as `SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.GetClientForm("WPQ2")`. So those two lines actually do the same thing:*

```
SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')
window.form.SubmitClientForm()
```

Comment: Wrong actionUrl parameter is causing the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried submitting the form with the form variable, that should work:

```
$("[name*='SaveItem']:visible").on("click", function(e){
        $("#loading").show();

        var answer = confirm("Save Item?");
        if (answer)
        {
            if (!PreSaveItem()){    
                return false;
            }

            if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')){                  
                return false;                   
            }   

            window.form.SubmitClientForm();
        }
        else{
            $("#loading").hide();
        }
    });
```

Change the dopostback with `window.form.SubmitClientForm();`

Comment: I tried your solution, but not worked for me.